# css box-flex showing incorrectly internet explorer

Tags: css

I have three divs in a row all filled with content. The 2 outer div's use a box stretch in css, this achieves the two outer div's to shirnk and the middle div to stay the same width as you shrink down the screen. That trick works great in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome. But for some reason it shows out of place in internet explorer. Does any one know of a trick for internet explorer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess I provided you the markup, so this will work I guess on IE 9+ or probably 10...? As IE is always late to accept new technology, so It will obviously not render correctly as I had used proprietary styles

Comment: IE10 supports old flex-box spec. Checkout msdn. They have good docs and examples

Answer (score 0):

Versions of IE older than 10 don't support the flexible box model. There is a polyfill available that you could try: https://github.com/doctyper/flexie